# A model for which the following is false, $\forall xR(x)\lor \forall xQ(x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Does the following model cause the formula below to equate to false?

$A = \{a,b\}$

$R^m = \{(a)\}$

$Q^m =\{(b)\}$

$\forall xR(x)\lor \forall xQ(x)$

How about $\forall x(R(x)\lor Q(x))$?

I am trying to get a better understanding of how the quantifiers qualify predicate symbols. According to my understanding, the model provided here should cause the first formula to equate to false but the latter to true.

Comment: Correct, well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\forall x R(x)\lor\forall x Q(x)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\forall x (R(x)\lor Q(x))
\end{equation}

To construct a model (also known as an interpretation) where $(1)$ and $(2)$ are false, you need only find a truth assignment that makes them false. For example, you can assert that every instance of $R(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are false, namely $\forall x\lnot R(x)$ and $\forall x\lnot Q(x)$.

A simple model that makes (2) true but (1) false is the following: $R(a)=1$, $R(b)=0$, $Q(a)=0$, $Q(b)=1$. This means that there is an R(x) that is false, and a Q(x) that is too, so $(1)$ is false. However, since $Q(x)$ is true when $R(x)$ is false, and vice versa, $(2)$ is true.

*I think this is what you were going for in your question, if it was, then your attempt is correct.*

Comment: Thanks. You say the "a simple model that makes (1) true but (2) false..." and then a bit later "so (1) is false....(2) is true." Is this a mistake or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Tightrope It was a typo, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I find this topic very difficult to grasp. Assume the same model. Does $\forall x R(x)\to \forall x Q(x)$ hold? In fact, I know it does, yet I don't understand why.

Comment: To illustrate the above. If $R(x) = 1$ then $Q(x)$ have to be true, $Q(x) = 1$, in order for the formula to be true. Yet, $R(x) = 1$ when its $x=a$ and $Q(x) = 0$ when its $x=b$ which would set the formula to false. However, according to my textbook the formula holds with this model so clearly im not understanding something properly.

Comment: $(\forall R(x))\rightarrow(\forall Q(x))$ means that if $R(x)$ holds for any $x$, then so does $Q(x)$ for all $x$. So, the example where $R(a)=1$ and $R(b)=0$ will not satisfy the antecedent of the implication. This mean that $\forall x Q(x)$ need not be true.

Comment: @Tightrope The implication as a whole will still be true however. As the antecedent $\forall x R(x)$ is false in that model, the implication is true by virtue of the principal of explosion. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)

Comment: I think it finally clicked. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You did that correctly.

Here is an intuitive one that works as well: Take as the domain all natural numbers (or integers), and interpret $R(x)$ as '$x$ is even' and $Q(x)$ as '$x$ is odd'